# So, where's that Flickr integration in iOS 7 and what API do I use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, flickr

I'm pretty desperate by now -- I can easily upload images to Twitter, Facebook, E-Mail, SMS etc. using very simple APIs.

However, I can't find any information what APIs to use for Flickr uploads.

There's a bunch of libraries that do it, but I thought it was "deeply integrated" into iOS 7 and all I'd need would... basically... be... a... "FRComposeViewController"? ;-)

Comment: `I can't find any information what APIs to use for Flickr uploads.` How about the [official Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)?

Answer (score 0):

`UIActivity`'s [`UIActivityTypePostToFlickr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_24) object "posts the provided image to the user’s Flickr account".

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your items using the `UIActivityViewController` to take advantage of flickr sharing.

```
UIActivityViewController * controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[image, message]                                                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^{
                 }];
```

Is all you need to do, where `image` is your `UIImage` instance and `message` can be an optional `NSString` instance.

The flickr sharing is a bit buried all the way over on the left...

[image]